# Logical error when comparing enum type

Tags: c++, enums, return, conditional-statements

I am trying to compare two enum values but during runtime it always seems to evaluate to true.

enum declaration in Table.h with return method to get value of status:

```
enum TableStatus { IDLE, SEATED, ORDERED, SERVED};

class Table
    {
    private:
            ...
            TableStatus status;     // current status
    public:
            ...
            TableStatus getTableStatus(void);
    }
```

In the section that I need to compare the enum value I've been trying conditionals that look like the following:

```
if (tables[tableId]->getTableStatus() == TableStatus(SERVED))
```

My question how to get this logic to work. In that comparing the status of the Table object to a certain enum value will evaluate correctly.

edit: Including getTableStatus(void);

```
TableStatus Table::getTableStatus(void){
        return status;
}
```

Comment: The code you show is correct for the task you describe.  There's a bug somewhere else if `getTableStatus()` is always returning `SERVED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into this same confusion when I use enum. Several times I have to look up a tutorial on enum to make sure I'm correct. I read this (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html) tutorial whenever I program using enums.

Basically Enums (C++98) do not behave like classes, so what you have written is not correct.
Enums can be referenced directly, so you have to write:

```
if (tables[tableId]->getTableStatus() == SERVED)
```

Provided the enum and the function where you are writing the code are in the same scope.

If you are using C++11, `enum classes` are a much better option. I like enum classes because I do not get confused with them as I used to do with C++98 enums.
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html